# How to vertically & horizontally center children elements in a fluid layout set by media queries?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, vertical-alignment, centering

I'm trying to achieve a certain fluid layout where the content of each DIVs are centered vertically and horizontally. But, my middle row (A, B, C) keeps on having vertical and/or horizontal alignment issues.

The goal is to have it work like this:

[image]

> **Note:** If there's a way I can have the option to set the Mobile layout's "C" area fluid as well (*without having to change the HTML, just the CSS, so that I can test which option works best*), that'd be a bonus!

Here's a snippet of the HTML:

```
<div class="page">
    <div class="col col-top">top</div>
    <div class="col col-mid">
        <div class="col col-left">
            <div class="centerBox"><div class='debugBox'></div></div>
        </div>
        <div class="col col-center">
            <div class="centerBox"><div class='debugBox'></div></div>
        </div>
        <div class="col col-right">
            <div class="centerBox"><div class='debugBox'></div></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col col-bottom">bottom</div>
</div>
```

I'm not sure if the "wrapper" DIVs with the "centerBox" class is really necessary (they're set as `display: table-cell` while each **col** class are set to `display: table` to *behave* like tables, but this causes issues to place those areas with `position: absolute` and % values for their left / right / top / bottom properties.

For instance, if the "C" area is set to `display: table`, this happens:

[image]

And if I change the "C" area to `display: block;`, then it fills that full center area, but...

[image]

... the horizontal and vertical alignment breaks inside of it.

Would using "Ghost" DIV elements (as discussed in this [css-tricks article](https://css-tricks.com/centering-in-the-unknown/), "Centering in the Unknown" by Chris Coyier ) be any better to get the correct alignment?

Comment: Ever thought about using a lib for this? Like bootstrap for instance?

Comment: you should read up on using CSS Flexbox

Comment: @Thomas: tbh I've never had experience with bootstrap. I was hoping for a solution that wouldn't rely on Javascript (pardon my ignorance if that has nothing to do with bootstrap!) but are you suggesting that it's easier to create complex fluid layouts with it (with variations for various screen sizes)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, this solution works without a framework, pure CSS using flexbox. As long as the layout is horizontal, C has a fixed width. When it is mobile, C takes up the whole width and has a variable height.

```css
header,
footer {
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: lightblue;
}
main {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

main > div {
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: tomato;
  flex-grow: 1;
  min-height: 40px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
main > div:nth-child(2) {
  background-color: olive;
}

.fixed {
  width: 400px;
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
  main {
    flex-direction: column;
  }
  .fixed {
    width: auto;
  }
}
```

```html
<header>Top</header>
<main>
  <div>A</div>
  <div class="fixed">C</div>
  <div>B</div>
</main>
<footer>Bottom</footer>
```

Here is a pen (drag the border to see the mobile layout):
[Codepen](http://codepen.io/wilmaknattern/pen/PPvPgK)

Comment: Nice use of flexbox... but you did not address the vertical alignment of the middle row.  Update the code to reflect that, and I would possibly concede to your answer :)

Comment: Yup... you're just missing **justify-content: center;** to get the items to center horizontally as well.  Now I'll +1 your answer :)  The only difference between yours and mine is that mine works in IE 9 and yours works in Opera Mini.  Two browsers that the rest of the world could care less about :)

Answer (score 1):

Here are the styles for the code you have provided.  The one thing to keep in mind is your middle column, being a fixed width, is what helps with the calc() function.  50% of HALF the width of the middle container.  This will not work in IE 8 or less, so you'll have to write a JS solution if you care about those browsers.

```
.page {
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
}

.col-top {
    background: #0f0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
}

.page .col-mid {
    width: 100%;
    display: table;
}

.page .col-mid .col {
    width: calc(50% - 250px);;
    height: 100px;
    background: #f00;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: center;
}

.page .col-mid .col-center {
    width: 500px;
    background: #00f;
}

.debugBox {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    background: #000;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.col-bottom {
    clear: both;
    height: 50px;
    background: #0f0;
}
```

and a working example here:

https://jsfiddle.net/g45pwedd/

And you don't need some of the container elements, as you stated.

**UPDATE**

Sorry, forgot to add for responsive.  I wasn't sure if you still needed vertical align for responsive or not.  This solution removes vertical align, as I doubt it's needed on a mobile display anyways:

```
@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .page .col-mid .col {
      display: block;
      width: 100%;
  }
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/g45pwedd/2/

Answer (score 0):

In **bootstrap 4**

to **center the childs horizontally**, use bootstrap-4 class

```
justify-content-center
```

to **center the childs vertically**, use bootstrap-4 class

```
 align-items-center
```

but remember don't forget to use d-flex class with these
it's a bootstrap-4 utility class, like so

```
<div class="d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center" style="height:100px;">
    <span class="bg-primary">MIDDLE</span>    
</div>
```

**Note:** make sure to add bootstrap-4 utilities if this code does not work